# VB .Net on Win10 program can't run

Tags: vb.net, initialization, startup

```
 Public Sub New()

    Dim stackframe As New Diagnostics.StackFrame

    Dim LogConfig As Log.Configure = New Log.Configure(My.Application.Info.ProductName)

    Log.EventLog.Write("Aplication Open")

    If Process.GetProcessesByName(My.Application.Info.ProductName).Length > 1 Then

        Log.ErrorLog.Write(stackframe.GetMethod.Name.ToString, "Application its running, can't duplicate it")

        End

    End If

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    Log.EventLog.Write("InitializeComponent")
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Log.EventLog.Write("ReadINI")
    If Not ReadINI(Application.StartupPath & "\" & Application.ProductName & ".ini") Then

        MsgBox("Failed!! Read ini file, please contact administrator", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")

        Log.ErrorLog.Write(stackframe.GetMethod.Name.ToString, "Read ini file failed")

        End

    End If
```

> 2020-02-06 11:38:03 [PCCLIENT]  Aplication Open
>
> 2020-02-06 11:38:03 [PCCLIENT]  InitializeComponent

I am trying to execute a program at a client PC with Windows 10 version 1803 until 1909 but can't run it.
I have checked, the log is stuck in InitializeComponent(), but I can't trace it.

Comment: If only there was a way for us to know what was inside that `InitializeComponent` method. The most obvious possibility seems to be that you are using a non-standard control that doesn't exist on the other machines but that's just a guess, because we have no other information to work with. Have you tried simplifying the app to the absolute basics and then building it up bit by bit until it breaks? That's problem-solving 101.

Comment: See in the System's Event Viewer if you can find the crash report. It should tell you what module failed.

Comment: I see the VB team put that `' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call` in for decoration rather than as an instruction to be heeded?